# "Надо оставить(,) как у Вас"

Tags: пунктуация

Написал в ответе такую фразу:

*...тогда, по-моему, надо оставить как у Вас.*

И не могу понять, действительно запятая перед "как" не нужна или всё-таки нужна. Понимаю, что если добавить "так" ("так, как у Вас"), то запятая точно нужна будет, но как правильно без "так"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**...тогда, по-моему, надо оставить как у Вас.**

Думаю, что **запятая не нужна**: пауза отсутствует, оборот является обстоятельством в основном сообщении.

**Примеры**

Государь ... предпочел **оставить как было написано**. [М. А. Корф. Записки (1838-1852)]

Иногда хочется все **оставить как есть** и не пытаться наладить!

Нажмут на все педали, чтобы все **оставить как было**.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не зря мне очень не хотелось её ставить!)

Answer (score 0):

Навскидку - я бы запятую сохранил. Да, "как у Вас" можно рассматривать и как член предложения (обстоятельство), не требующий обособления. Но это, боюсь, вызовет массу вопросов.

Если вопрос не разрешится, позже уточню, сейчас нет возможности смотреть справочники.

Comment: Спасибо! Пока подожду всё-таки с исправлением, почему-то очень не хочется её ставить.)